# Nginx + WordPress pretty permalinks return 404

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks

Stuck even after having gone through all nginx + WordPress permalinks issue raised here.

I have WordPress installed in a subdirectory `digitext-v1`. Root directory only has phpinfo file.

```
root -->    /var/www
subdirectory -->   /var/www/digitext-v1
```

Plain permalinks work fine with home and all pages. Pretty permalinks work with home page but gives 404 error for all others.

My conf file is given below. Has almost identical setup (except for fqdn used in server name) to my live Nginx server where pretty permalinks work perfectly fine.

Can you help me resolve it before I lose my sanity? Anything to do with domain name? What am I doing wrong??

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name digitextv1 192.168.11.8;

    root   /var/www/digitext-v1;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;


    location / {
    # Setting pretty permalinks in WordPress
    # First attempt to serve request as file ($uri)
    # or directory ($uri/).
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**EDIT (few lines from error log)**

```
2021/08/31 16:05:48 [error] 3185#3185: *1406 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/digitext-v1/wp-content/plugins/popup-maker/includes/functions/popups/template.php on line 106PHP message: PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/digitext-v1/wp-content/plugins/popup-maker/includes/functions/popups/template.php on line 106" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.11.41, server: 192.168.11.8, request: "GET /digitext-v1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.11.8", referrer: "http://192.168.11.8/digitext-v1/wp-admin/options-permalink.php"
2021/08/31 16:06:28 [error] 3185#3185: *1426 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/digitext-v1/wp-content/plugins/popup-maker/includes/functions/popups/template.php on line 106" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.11.41, server: 192.168.11.8, request: "GET /digitext-v1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.11.8"
2021/08/31 16:06:28 [error] 3185#3185: *1426 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/digitext-v1/wp-content/plugins/popup-maker/includes/functions/popups/template.php on line 106PHP message: PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/digitext-v1/wp-content/plugins/popup-maker/includes/functions/popups/template.php on line 106" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.11.41, server: 192.168.11.8, request: "GET /digitext-v1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.11.8"
2021/08/31 16:09:59 [error] 3185#3185: *1438 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/digitext-v1/wp-content/plugins/popup-maker/includes/functions/popups/template.php on line 106" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.11.41, server: 192.168.11.8, request: "GET /digitext-v1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.11.8", referrer: "http://192.168.11.8/digitext-v1/wp-admin/options-permalink.php"
2021/08/31 16:09:59 [error] 3185#3185: *1438 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/digitext-v1/wp-content/plugins/popup-maker/includes/functions/popups/template.php on line 106PHP message: PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/digitext-v1/wp-content/plugins/popup-maker/includes/functions/popups/template.php on line 106" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.11.41, server: 192.168.11.8, request: "GET /digitext-v1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.11.8", referrer: "http://192.168.11.8/digitext-v1/wp-admin/options-permalink.php"
```

Comment: Have you reset the browser cache. I can see nothing wrong with your configuration. Show the access log and error log entries for one of these 404 responses.

Comment: Cleared cache, tried private/incognito browser sessions. Does using non-FQDN in server_name cause it? I see nothing on 404 responses in error log (added in the question).

Comment: You have a try_files inside of your php location config.

Comment: Already tried removing try_files from php location. Doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same issue this week. I even went so far as to reset WordPress, without success. I uploaded my `.htacess` file to my host advisor Chris at easy.dns and after some back and forth he deleted the following code to solve the problem:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
<Files *config.json*>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: I believe the equivalent of Rewrite rules from Apache web server is try_files in Nginx webserver, which I use. I tried various try_files rules in conf file with no success.